# Remote Access when sandboxes are refreshed

Tags: salesforce, sandbox

Does Remote Access configuration (client secret, users' security tokens) change when you refresh a Sandbox?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The org id does, and the server can. No idea about the other stuff though.

Answer (score 0):

Yes all of the security information will change after a sandbox refresh. User passwords and tokens will match what the values were in production at the time the refresh was created. Remote site settings will also carry over from production.

In fact we have it a manual process step after a refresh to update the remote site settings and our web service configuration to point back to our QA environments.